# How to skip an element when iterating through a list Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, watir

I have the following script which loops through an element list:

```
  $browser.divs(class:'menu-index-page__menu-category').map do |cat|
  cate = cat.h3.text
  puts cate

  cc = cat.ul(class:'menu-index-page__items')
  cc.lis(class:'menu-index-page__item').each do |lit|
    lit.fire_event :click
    sleep(5)
```

Once in a while the name of the class list changes to:

```
menu-index-page__item menu-index-page__item--unavailable
```

This breaks the script, and I want to be able to skip this whenever it comes up and continue with the original script.

[image]

Comment: `next if condition`... I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Watir v6.5+, the :class locator supports excluding classes. You can find all elements that include class "a", but not "b" by doing:

```
browser.elements(class: ['a', '!b'])
```

For your specific example, you can do:

```
cc.lis(class: ['menu-index-page__item', '!menu-index-page__item--unavailable']).each do |lit|
  # your actions on lit
end
```

Comment: I would like to click on 'menu-index-page__item' and ignore/skip '!menu-index-page__item--unavailable' right now it tries to click on '!menu-index-page__item--unavailable' which is what breaks the script.

Comment: That is what this would do. It would only iterate over the `li` that have "menu-index-page__item" but do not have "menu-index-page__item--unavailable". So your click would only be on these ones you want.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the statement "once in a while the name of the class list changes". When does the class change? If it's before you run the above loop, this solution works. If it changes while you are iterating, we'll need a different solution.

Comment: ahhh perfect I didn't pay attention to the exclamation mark, works superbly. Many Thanks

Comment: If this answer answers your question , please accept this answer. You need to click the tic below the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

When you include the lis using class, you have to be careful because when you locate using `menu-index-page__item`, it locates everything which **includes** `menu-index-page__item` so it locates `menu-index-page__item menu-index-page__item--unavailable` as well. So try forming xpath in this place, it would work

```
$browser.divs(class: 'menu-index-page__menu-category').map do |cat|
  cate = cat.h3.text
  puts cate

  cc = cat.ul(class: 'menu-index-page__items')
  cc.lis(xpath: "//li[@class='menu-index-page__item']").each do |lit|
    lit.fire_event :click
  end
end
```

Or you can exclude the specific list this way

```
$browser.divs(class:'menu-index-page__menu-category').map do |cat|
  cate = cat.h3.text
  puts cate

  cc = cat.ul(class:'menu-index-page__items')
  cc.lis(xpath: "//li[not(@class=menu-index-page__item menu-index-page__item--unavailable')]").each do |lit|
    lit.fire_event :click
  end
end
```

And also never do click via `fireevent` because that's the javascript click, it's not a selenium click, you would be missing many events which would be triggered after the click.

So perform

```
lit.click
```

Comment: I think the :css example would still match all items. You'd have to explicitly exclude the unavailable class.

Comment: @JustinKo Yeah , you are right, I thought about that while I was writing it, I will remove it now. Thanks.